# insert a document to jscrollpane

Tags: java, textarea, jscrollpane

I would like to display a document (text and images) into a JScrollPane. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a JTextPane. JScrollPane is for normal texts but if you want document handling with styles and fonts and those stuff you see in text editors, you need JTextPane or JEditorPane.

You can do a search for the sample usage for JTextPane and JEditorPane.

Comment: thanks so much. how can i create a DefaultStyledDocument using an rtf (or related) file?

Comment: A sample: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneStylesExample1.htm

Do a Google search: "DefaultStyledDocument example".